# Display selected row in new tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a plain tableview displaying several sections and rows with the content of a plist. Whenever a row is selected, I want to display the content of that row (so the exact same row) in a new grouped tableview. Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

EDIT: having this code now:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *selectedMatch = [self.matchesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"%@", [selectedMatch description]);
    NSLog(@"IndexPath: %@", [indexPath description]);

    DetailTableViewController *dvController = [[DetailTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    dvController.selectedMatch = selectedMatch;
    [dvController release];
    dvController = nil;
}
```

Comment: are the rows in your table backed by model objects?

Comment: Rows are populated by means of a plist, containing an array of dictionaries. Every dictionary contains the info for one row.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that when you select your row by tapping on it you push or present modally a new tableviewController. So simply subclass this newTableviewController to receive an indexPath ... the same indexPath that correspond to your selected row. So in the newTableviewController you can send selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition: to your newTableView to show selection of the the new row correspondent to the row of your previous table.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried some code, but no success yet. I can't get  the selected row to be displayed in the new tableview yet. What do you think about the code above? And any thoughts on what I have to add in the new tableview's code?